# HTML, Nested Div problem

Tags: html, nested

In my page I have three sections Header, Body and Footer.
In body I have three divs. First div includes another two small divs.

I wrote this CSS code:

```
#body_container{
    margin: 10px 160px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #3F0;
}

div.body_contents{
    height: auto;
    width: 74%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #960;
}

div.sidebar{
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #F0F;
}
```

but when I check it, div is out of my frame. I gave 160px margin of left and right. what should i do?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: 1st you should provide a minimum of html code so the answerer could reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate using percentages since they depends on other things.

I usually do something with static values, like :

```
#body_container{
    margin: 10px auto; /** The auto will make this div centered to the page **/
    width: 1000px; /** suppose you want this width **/
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #3F0;
}

div.body_contents{
    width: 748px; /** The width of the main part, -2px (for the border) **/
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #960;
}

div.sidebar{
    width: 248px; /** The width of the side bar, -2px (for the border) **/
    border: 1px solid #F0F;
}
```

Of course, if you want the width of you main div to change regarding of the size of the browser (as it would be with your original CSS), my answer doesn't work.

But I would recommend you to NOT do a change of width based on the browser since it would change the organization of your page depending on the window.

Comment: Thanks for your guide, as you predict I want to change anything regards to changing browser. but your recommendation is so helpful. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

That's simple, `margin` adds to the final rendered width of the element (that's 160 x 2 + 100% of parent's width, so it is overflow), so you may want to make it, for example, for the outer div, that width is 79%, and the left and right margin is 10% each (so total is 99%, 1% less to allow some room for borders, etc... although that's usually not how I do it)

example:  http://jsfiddle.net/MKjwU/6/

one more thing: to clear the floats, you don't clear it like in your example...

either use an extra div, like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/MKjwU/7/

or using this technique:  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

see it at: http://jsfiddle.net/MKjwU/8/